# Call server in background

Tags: ios4, chat, asihttprequest, background-process

I'm building an iPhone-app in which the logged in users can chat to each other. It's very like the Wordfeud chat for example. You click a user and a modal view controller shows up where you chat.

I have set up a push notification server that works, I just need to know just how I should use it.

When the chat view controller is open I poll in the background with ASIHttpRequest every tenth second to see if a message has been sent from the user you chat with. This works perfectly fine.

But what happends when i close the chat view controller to do something else in the app. Should I create a ASIHttpRequest in every single view controller in the app to poll for new messages or is it here the push notification service takes over? Even though the app is still open?

Or shouldn't I send push notifications when the app is running, only when it's not running?
If that's the case I guess I have to send a request to the server which says that the app is has now been closed (here is a problem if the app crashed out of the blue).

I would be really greatful for some guidelines here, I have searched the web but there are old discussions which confuses me, and some new ones where many people says different.